# Is overriding operators with #prepend dangerous?

Tags: ruby

I am building a gem that makes an `ActiveRecord` immutable. The details do not matter, but basically, one thing this allows is for `user.country == :CAN` to return `true` if the country's code attribute match.

Of course, this means that `:CAN == user.country` will never work unless I override the `==` operator on `Symbol`, which I am wondering if this is a dangerous thing to do, maybe because of the added overhead, since this operator is used extensively everywhere.

Is there a better/smarter way to do exactly that? `#coerce` is not an option because `Symbol` already knows how to `==`.

```
Symbol.prepend(Module.new do
  def ==(other)
    if other.respond_to?(:immutable?) && other.immutable?
      other.==(self)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end)
```

If it changes anything, my main issue also has to do with the `===` operator, since I wanted to enable the following:

```
case user.country
  when :CAN then ...
  when :USA then ...
  else ...
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If this is a very dangerous thing to do. Being able to do it doesn't mean it should be done, and I feared this could be the case here.

Comment: For example, `something.send(:private_method)` is valid, but I think everyone would say that it should NOT be done.

Comment: Personally, I'd never do this. Not even because this is dangerous, but because it is a huuuge WTF-moment. Reading ruby code, one can kinda expect that equality operators work "normally".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev as a matter of fact, triple-equal aka case-equal is _intended_ to be overwritten. For normal `==` I’d avoid overwriting, yes.

Comment: @mudasobwa: it's commonly known as "threequals", btw :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I guess I am a persona non grata in that community since I have never heard this term.

Comment: @mudasobwa: for this example to work, we'd need to amend `Symbol#===`. It doesn't _feel_ right.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it does feel perfectly right since we have `super` in  `prepend`ed modules. C’mon, man, it’s ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa: must be I'm reaching the age when I start fearing change and uncertainty. I guess I should start looking at java :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sure thing. COBOL is also good in our ages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165975/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-mudasobwa).

Comment: Fun to understand that I don't have enough "reputation" to even take part in the chat.

So, I take it overriding `#===` would work, but would be a bad practice.

Comment: @Zyrthofar: as you can see, it's very much opinion-based. My opinion is to not do this without real need. mudasobwa disagrees.

Comment: @Zyrthofar: ah but yes, it would work.

Comment: What does `user.country` return?

Comment: @Stefan A normal `Country` record.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input!

Comment: Would't it be easier to check for `:CAN == user.country.code`?

Comment: You'll really want to steer away from putting in core extensions on Symbol to handle quirky behaviour like this. In Ruby the `==` comparison is directional, this is expected by anyone familiar with the language, and `a == b` is not obligated to be the same as `b == a` except under constraints imposed by things like [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Comparable.html).

Comment: Why can't you do this with strings or, better still, some kind of Country object so you can do `user.country == Country.canada`?

Comment: All this has helped me decide _not_ to implement these backward comparisons, and in fact to completely remove the current behavior described in the question description. Thank you!